# How to search with special characters using azure suggestion Search (Node)

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cognitive-search, azure-cognitive-services

Lets say I have a cosmosdb with the following data

`{id: 1, name : "$abc"}, {id: 2, name : "cdf>>"}, {id : 3,name : "xyz"}`

I'm using azure search api to search through the index of this collection using **Node JS**.

```
api post body : {
filter : ,
search: ,
top: ,
suggesterName:,
}
```

In the request body for search parameter .
If I give special characters directly or by escaping the special characters I'm getting an error saying Invalid Search Syntax (search : '$' or search : '$') .

When I URL encode the search string and send it to the api the error doesn't occur. But searching with special characters doesn't work (say search : '$' ($ will be encoded) -> wont return {id: 1, name: "$abc"}, but searching with search : 'x' -> returns  {id : 3, name : "xyz"}).

Can anyone help me understand , What I need to do to get response from azure api even while searching with special characters as I'm really new to azure.

Comment: Pls allow to post my test details below, and could you pls share further details if my code not work? Thanks in advance for your response.

Comment: Is there any progress? If you got any further questions, pls feel free to add here. And could you pls accept my post as the answer if it is of some help to you? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested in my side, and you can see the following screenshot, it's ok to get the result. The same as using sdk. Could you pls try my query or provide more details on how you creating index or your code?

By rest api post request:

```
const options = {
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json',
            'api-key': 'B556BCC1715872292DB1878EA4FB7EE9'
        }
    };
    axios.post('https://search_service_name.search.windows.net/indexes/index_name/docs/search?api-version=2020-06-30-Preview', 
        { "search": "$abc" }, options)
        .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
    });
```

[image]

With sdk:

```
const indexClient = new SearchIndexClient(endpoint, new AzureKeyCredential(apiKey));
const searchClient = indexClient.getSearchClient(indexName);
searchOptions = {
        searchFields: ["name"]
    };

    searchResults = await searchClient.search("cdf>>", searchOptions);
    for await (const result of searchResults.results) {
        console.log(`${JSON.stringify(result.document)}`);
    }
```

[image]

Call api in tools:
[image]

And this is my data in the collection:

```
{
    "id": "3",
    "category": "fun",
    "name": "$abc",
    "description": "Complete Cosmos DB Node.js Quickstart ⚡",
    "isComplete": true,
    "_rid": "zJlUAP-8snQCAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/zJlUAA==/colls/zJlUAP-8snQ=/docs/zJlUAP-8snQCAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"9e0123dd-0000-1800-0000-608661760000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1619419510
},
{
    "id": "4",
    "category": "fun",
    "name": "cdf>>",
    "description": "aasssddd",
    "isComplete": true,
    "_rid": "zJlUAP-8snQDAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/zJlUAA==/colls/zJlUAP-8snQ=/docs/zJlUAP-8snQDAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"9e0128dd-0000-1800-0000-608661970000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1619419543
}
```